# Measure compute shader execution time in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gpgpu

Is there a way to measure the execution time of a given compute shader in Unity ?

I thought to "artificialy" add a compute buffer in this compute shader and make a ["getData"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ComputeBuffer.GetData.html) on it, because I know this function will block the cpu, until the gpu calculation is over. But, it seems a bit rough as a method... moreover, how to know how long the getdata will last in this case ?

Another solution I tried, was to used [GraphicsFence](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.GraphicsFence.html) and to check when it's `passed` property was set to true, but I can only do it in coroutine which are called once per frame, therefore the estimation of the execution time will be always greater than the duration of a frame...

Comment: You cannot know how long `GetData` will be, but if your compute shader is long enough, the time spent retrieving something like a byte from the GPU will be negligeable (you will only pay the price of the API overhead)

Comment: I try to use `GetData` with just a int, the execution time for my dispatch is 930 µs with this method, and using the profiler of [renderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/) it tells me that my execution time is 400 µs... Do you have an idea to explain this difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen that it's possible to retrieve data written in the Unity Profiler. So I programmed a little tool to retrieve this data and calculate an average time for a given compute shader.

The tool is available at this link: https://github.com/davidAlgis/com.studio-nyx.compute-shader-performance-estimation.

Although slow, it gives a good idea of the average execution time of a compute shader without having to code anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe measuring the time between Dispatch and [AsyncGPUReadbackRequest.done](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.AsyncGPUReadbackRequest-done.html) helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).